# Creating Surveys with accepts_nested_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, survey, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been working with rails3 and have been trying to create a simple survey application but some issues have come up. I can create questions just fine but when it comes to creating a survey that people can take I come accross some issues. For one the answers aren't being assigned a :user_id or :survey_id. The following is a copy of my controllers, models and views.

Survey Controller

```
def take
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  @questions = @survey.questions
  @answers = @questions.map{|q| q.answers.build}
  @answers.each do |a|
    a.survey_id = @survey.id
    a.user_id = current_user.id
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html #
  end
end

def submit
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @survey.update_attributes(params[:survey])
      format.html { redirect_to(@survey, :notice => 'Survey was successfully submitted.')}
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @survey.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Survey Model

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :answers, :through => :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_presence_of :name, :user_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Questions Model

```
    class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :survey
     has_many :answers
     validates_presence_of :question_string, :question_type
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true
    end
```

Answers Model

```
    class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :question
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :survey
    end
```

Take View

```
    %h1 Take the survey
    - semantic_form_for @survey, :url => { :action => "submit" } do |s|
     - if @survey.errors.any?
        %p= pluralize(@survey.errors.count, "error") + " prohibited this survey from being saved"
        #survey_errors
         - @survey.errors.full_messages.each do |err_msg|
            %p= err_msg
     #survey_details.header
     = s.fields_for :questions do |q|
        = q.fields_for :answers do |a|
         = render 'answer_fields', :s => a

     .actions
        = s.commit_button
```

Questions Partial

```
    #questions_form.fields
     = s.input :question_string, :label => "Question: "
     = s.input :question_type, :as => :radio, :collection => [1,2,3,4], :label => "Question Type:"
     = s.hidden_field :_destroy
     = link_to_function  "Remove Question", "remove_fields(this)"
```

Answers Partial

```
    #answers_form.fields
     = s.label :answer_string, "Answer"
     = s.text_field :answer_string
     = s.hidden_field :question_id
```

Routes.rb

```
    resources :surveys do
        get 'take', :on => :member
        put 'submit', :on => :member
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding another hidden field with the user id in your answers partial.

```
s.hidden_field :user_id, :value => x
```

That is how I have done hidden fields, you are just putting the variables in there. I have encountered merge problems by not passing it as key value pair.

---

What are you using? HAML, I don't really understand how that is working.

This is all you need for everything to work.

Survey model

```
has_many :answers
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true
```

The controller doesn't need additional code

The view needs `fields_for`

```
 <% f.fields for :answers do |f| %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: thank you. that worked...but how do i make it so that it only updates their answers now. because if i fill out the form and refresh after the answers are created...it returns the forms filled with the old answers and new answers

Comment: I'm not sure about why the old and new answers are getting displayed. Do you mean duplicates are getting created? I just not too sure.